# Phonegap 2.1 support for Iphone 5 display

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios-simulator

I updated to phonegap 2.1 with the hope of being able to deal with 4 inch retina display of new Iphone 5. (I am not sure if they ever promised to support it anyway)

The problem is that (as you guessed), when I change the device to Iphone 4 inch display in IOS simulator, this is how it looks like. How to deal with the black stripes on top and bottom ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is to add another splash image: Add a Default-568h@2x.png image, at 640 x 1136 px and it will work.

For next time: Google is your friend ;)

Comment: I Googled and got to this page. So I'm glad that he asked.